# Sentiment analysis: more than 3 sentiments

Tags: java, nlp, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

My app needs sentiment analysis functionality. I've found plenty of services and libraries which can help with this task. But most of them have "three-dimensional" output: the text may be classified as "positive", "negative" or "neutral.

But what if I need larger variety of options? For example: "confident/doubtful", "calm/alerted", "kind/aggressive" or something like that.

Is it even possible to perform such classification? May be there are already some services/frameworks/libraries available?

Comment: If you want more fine-grained analysis, you might have to do some machine-learning and train your analyzer to recognize what things are "confident/doubtful", etc.

Comment: OK: are there any trainsets/corpuses available for such kind of machine-learning?

Comment: I'm pretty new to the area in general, so I cannot say definitively. You could try looking, but if these are your own classifications, you would have to train it on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [WordNet-Affect](http://wndomains.fbk.eu/wnaffect.html). This ressource provides a tree of emotions. As it is a quite old ressource, you will have to manually parsed it and to map the IDs with [WordNet 1.6](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/old-versions/) synsets (I did this work in Python [here](https://github.com/clemtoy/WNAffect)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Machine Learning algorithm. I have used "Support Vector Machine" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) for sentiment analysis.

Support Vector Machine is a supervised algorithm, so you need to train the algorithm with data previously classified (confident, doubtful, calm, alerted, kind, aggressive). Finally, you will get a model that you can use to classify new text.

I have used the LibSVM library with phyton (https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) with good results. I think you can also use it with java.

Comment: Any ideas where do I get corresponding training set?

Comment: It is difficult to find a training set specific for your needs. I used this dataset: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/ (my objective was analyse sentiments regarding to movies). Other option is  classify your data manually.